# UICollectionview drag and drop issue when scroll type is horizontal

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, drag-and-drop

I am using dragInteraction for drag and drop feature in UICollectionview. Everything works fine but when i change my scroll direction to horizontal the behaviour of dragging changed.

Ref : https://hackernoon.com/drag-it-drop-it-in-collection-table-ios-11-6bd28795b313

I mean when i use vertical scrolling the behaviour of dragging looks good like it shifted the positions, but in horizontal scrolling the behaviour is different.

like : for Horizontal which has the issue https://i.stack.imgur.com/qH3ru.jpg and  vertical which works fine 
       https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5t92.jpg

I have tried to find solution but not found solution for this issue, i want same behaviour of dragging while in horizontal scrolling.

Comment: I think the problem is in destinationIndexPath section, check it out

Comment: the issue occur while dragging, before dropping its before my logic related destinationIndexPath

Comment: maybe there is some func like shouldMoveCellToIndexPath where you can check paths?

Comment: yes there is method like collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem]

Comment: Vertically it looks good but horizontally also the behaviour of dragging is same like vertical.

Comment: can you share your code? how did you implemented UICollectionViewDropCoordinator?

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik sure https://github.com/pgpt10/DragAndDrop-CollectionView

Comment: check Collection View2 and change scroll direction to horizontal and when we Apply swap the result is different  then vertical

Comment: I tried your app, changed scrollDirection to horizontal it works correct. You forgot that your second collectionView filling from top to bottom and then from left to right. To understand what am I talking about, try to swap them in column. To debug add rows number to cell labels, to see the order of cells

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197219/discussion-between-guru-and-alexandr-kolesnik).

Comment: Why downvote??????